# How to count Pandas rows when value = x?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, count

I have a table that looks like this:

```
  Customer      Product     Amount
     A           Table        500  
     A           Table        300
     A           Chair        100
     B           Rug           50
     B           Chair        200
```

And I simply want to count the number of rows where Product = "Table"

here is what I have:

```
  df['Product'] == 'Table'
```

and here is that I get:

```
  0    True
  1    True
  2    False
  3    False
  4    False
```

I have also tried this:

```
  len(df['Product'])
```

and get this:

```
 5
```

which is the count of all the rows. I am not sure what I am missing or doing wrong?

I just want the result to say '2', or count the True/false from above, so result would be:

True = 2
   False = 3

Something like that.

Comment: `df.Product.value_counts()['Table']`

Comment: @sacul, your answer's worth keeping.

Comment: Just thought it's probably a duplicate, and can be answered succinctly enough in a comment :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
len(df[df['Product'] == 'Table'])
```

or

```
df[df['Product'] == 'Table'].shape[0]
```

or

```
(df['Product'] == 'Table').sum()
```

or

```
import numpy as np
np.sum(df['Product'] == 'Table')
```

Comment: wow, I knew I was missing something simple.  Makes perfect sense.  Thank you.  Will accept it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby(['Product'])['Product'].count()
```

Will give you a count of all the unique product names

```
Out[5]: 
Product
Chair    2
Rug      1
Table    2
Name: Product, dtype: int64
```